# Docusign Connect - sends two AutoResponded event requests for a single AutoResponded event

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign Connect appears to be sending us a duplicate envelope event for the Auto Responded event.

The flow seems to go like this:

1. `AutoResponded` event comes through (with no reason attached) indicating to users there is a problem

I now go into the Docusign console, fix the email and 're-send' the envelope

2. `Sent` event comes through
3. `AutoResponded` event comes through again with reason attached even though envelope was successfully sent

---

Question:
Why is the second `AutoResponded` event being sent and how do I stop it? It seems like a bug!

---

Here are the XML logs:

#### 1. the first `AutoResponded` event is sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <Email>bad_email@gmail.com</Email>
                <UserName>Agent Sign</UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>2020-04-29T12:18:27.73</Sent>
                <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
                <AutoRespondedReason />
                <Status>AutoResponded</Status>
                <RecipientIPAddress />
                <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
                <RecipientId>5c0a8b5a-29e6-4202-a2cb-3c1ee8a5dabd</RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        <TimeGenerated>2020-04-29T12:18:28.8995763</TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>e8a9f23a-e49d-4f51-b960-3e80d20c11b3</EnvelopeID>
        <Subject>A subject</Subject>
        <UserName>My Account</UserName>
        <Email>my_email</Email>
        <Status>Sent</Status>
        <Created>2020-04-29T12:18:26.123</Created>
        <Sent>2020-04-29T12:18:28.23</Sent>
        <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
        <ACStatusDate>2020-04-29T12:18:26.123</ACStatusDate>
        <ACHolder>My account</ACHolder>
        <ACHolderEmail>my_email</ACHolderEmail>
        <ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation>
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <SenderIPAddress>52**** </SenderIPAddress>
        <EnvelopePDFHash />
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <DocumentStatuses>
            <DocumentStatus>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>My document</Name>
                <TemplateName />
                <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            </DocumentStatus>
        </DocumentStatuses>
    </EnvelopeStatus>
    <TimeZone>GMT Standard Time</TimeZone>
    <TimeZoneOffset>1</TimeZoneOffset>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

#### 2. After manually fixing email address and resending, the `Sent` event is sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <Email>good_email@gmail.com</Email>
                <UserName>Agent Sign</UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>2020-04-29T12:20:03.667</Sent>
                <DeclineReason />
                <Status>Sent</Status>
                <RecipientIPAddress />
                <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
                <RecipientId>5c0a8b5a-29e6-4202-a2cb-3c1ee8a5dabd</RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        <TimeGenerated>2020-04-29T12:20:03.8080578</TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>e8a9f23a-e49d-4f51-b960-3e80d20c11b3</EnvelopeID>
        <Subject>A subject</Subject>
        <UserName>My Account</UserName>
        <Email>my_email</Email>
        <Status>Sent</Status>
        <Created>2020-04-29T12:18:26.123</Created>
        <Sent>2020-04-29T12:18:28.23</Sent>
        <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
        <ACStatusDate>2020-04-29T12:18:26.123</ACStatusDate>
        <ACHolder>My account</ACHolder>
        <ACHolderEmail>my_email</ACHolderEmail>
        <ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation>
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <SenderIPAddress>52*** </SenderIPAddress>
        <EnvelopePDFHash />
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <DocumentStatuses>
            <DocumentStatus>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>My document</Name>
                <TemplateName />
                <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            </DocumentStatus>
        </DocumentStatuses>
    </EnvelopeStatus>
    <TimeZone>GMT Standard Time</TimeZone>
    <TimeZoneOffset>1</TimeZoneOffset>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

#### 3. Immediately after a second `AutoResponded` event is sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <Email>good_email@gmail.com</Email>
                <UserName>Agent Sign</UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>2020-04-29T12:20:03.667</Sent>
                <DeclineReason />
                <AutoRespondedReason>
                    <![CDATA[smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser r18si2079394ilc.128 - gsmtp]]>
                </AutoRespondedReason>
                <Status>AutoResponded</Status>
                <RecipientIPAddress />
                <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
                <RecipientId>5c0a8b5a-29e6-4202-a2cb-3c1ee8a5dabd</RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        <TimeGenerated>2020-04-29T12:20:05.0110985</TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>e8a9f23a-e49d-4f51-b960-3e80d20c11b3</EnvelopeID>
        <Subject>A subject</Subject>
        <UserName>My account</UserName>
        <Email>my_email</Email>
        <Status>Sent</Status>
        <Created>2020-04-29T12:18:26.123</Created>
        <Sent>2020-04-29T12:20:03.933</Sent>
        <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
        <ACStatusDate>2020-04-29T12:18:26.123</ACStatusDate>
        <ACHolder>My account</ACHolder>
        <ACHolderEmail>my_email</ACHolderEmail>
        <ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation>
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <SenderIPAddress>52.**** </SenderIPAddress>
        <EnvelopePDFHash />
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <DocumentStatuses>
            <DocumentStatus>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>document_name</Name>
                <TemplateName />
                <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            </DocumentStatus>
        </DocumentStatuses>
    </EnvelopeStatus>
    <TimeZone>GMT Standard Time</TimeZone>
    <TimeZoneOffset>1</TimeZoneOffset>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

---

And here is the configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug, but the bug is not that you got two AutoResponded messages. That is actually normal in some cases. If the SMTP server takes time to give the reason, but DocuSign already knows the email was not delivered, then the second one is sent to give you the reason which DocuSign only knows later. The first one is sent quickly so you can know as soon as possible that it wasn't delivered, even if no reason is provided.
Now, the bug here may be that the second one already updated the email address as it's coming from an internal database, but the bounce was for a different email address.
I can file a bug on this and ask someone to investigate and fix, if you want, but in the interim I suggest you change your logic of your app. If you got the "sent" notification for a specific recipientID - you can ignore any AutoResponded messages for the same recipient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I find that functionality quite confusing and it does still seem somewhat buggy.

Is the multiple `Auto Responded` messages documented anywhere?
Why does the second `Auto Responded` message get sent only AFTER I successfully re-send the envelope?
Are there any other events that can trigger multiple webhook requests?

I don't want to have to work out if I've processed this event already. I should be able to only configure it so that I receive only one event request per actual Docusign event/status-change. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, Im trying to get answers, but I don't know if/when I'll get them. Like I said, I do think there's a bug here.

Comment: HI inbar, is there any progress on this? again it really does feel like a bug to receive this event twice and in the pattern that I have described.

Comment: Do you mind sending me an email with all the relevant details, most importantly your accountID (GUID form) and I'll work to get you an update directly. (inbar.gazit@docusign.com)